# Get coordinates of most recent remaining finger - Android Multitouch

Tags: android, pointers, multi-touch, touchscreen, ontouch

The problem I'm facing is that at the time ACTION_POINTER_UP is fired, I need to grab the coordinates of the most recent *remaining* finger.

Take this example (Using 2 pointers):

- Place thumb onto screen (ID0)
- Place Index Finger onto screen (ID1)
- Lift thumb from screen (ID0)
- Remaining pointer is Index Finger (ID1)
- Grab coordinates of index finger (ID1)

Now, within my ACTION_POINTER_UP case, I have the following:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {

    y = event.getY();
    x = event.getX();                                   
    break;                                          
 }
```

Obviously, this isn't much use because (as far as I can make out), this records the x and y of the pointer that left the screen, which *isn't* what I need.

The above example is using only 2 pointers, but the same question could be applied to 3, 4 or 5 pointers.

- Place Thumb onto screen (ID0)
- Place Index finger onto screen (ID1)
- Place Middle finger onto screen (ID2)
- Place Ring finger onto screen (ID3)
- Lift thumb from screen (ID0)
- Grab x and y of most recent of the remaining pointers to have touched the sceeen

Please do not link to any official Android documentation or blogs, I've read them multiple times and I still don't really understand how I can achieve this.  Also, please correct me if my understanding of pointer ID's is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Since MotionEvent's getDownTime() method only applies to the initial pointer down, and remains constant until all pointers have gone up, you will have to maintain your own data structure which maps the pointer id to the time that you got an ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_DOWN for that pointer. For the time of these ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_DOWN events use getEventTime().

For completeness, since you mention not being sure of your understanding of pointer IDs, I mention in passing that the pointer index is not persistent, only the ID. So make sure that you are clear on this before you use the MotionEvent methods which retrieve information about a pointer.

Also event.getX() returns the value for pointer index zero and is equivalent to event.getX(0).